# Docker Container systemctl broken when docker stop/restart

Tags: docker, systemctl

## Environment

- Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
- Docker (latest)

## Code

```bash
sudo docker run --gpus all -it -p 8888:8888 -p 5222:22 --name jupytorch-main pytorch/pytorch:2.0.1-cuda11.7-cudnn8-devel
```

## Situation

I am a data scientist. I use Jupyter Lab using a docker container. But, at this time, I move to **VSCode**. So I need access to the container with **SSH**. So, I need to use a systemctl in the container. But this problem is not easy.

## Problem

The `systemctl` is working well at the first start of the container. But, after stopping/restarting the container, the problems related with `PID 1` in docker are started. So, if the all docker demon is ideally stopped (like Linux log out) and restarted, all problem is solved.

But, If I manage many containers and just one container is stopped, I need to restart all docker demons containing all containers.

So, related management is conducted by gdraheim ([Link](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement)). But I cannot understand that I don't know the solution, just understand the problem.

My solution(: *stop/restart all docker demons*) is not the perfect solution. What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: My solution is not working. The `PID-1` problem is sustained when restarting all docker demons on Ubuntu. It only works on **Windows**.

Comment: I use `pytorch/pytorch` base Image

Comment: Why exactly do you need to ssh into the container?  (If you were running Jupyter without Docker, when and why would you need to "go inside" the process?)  Can you use `docker exec`, or better a workflow that doesn't need an interactive shell at all?  ssh in a container is hard to set up securely, and systemd in a container is not typically a best practice.

Comment: This having been said: you haven't included any of the source code necessary to reproduce the problem, which makes this difficult to solve.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm so late. I think **VSCode** is better choice than Jupyter Lab. And I just know that **SSH** is only [method](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) to connect my workstation using **VSCode**. Is there any other method?  @DavidMaze